# Wheel of luck - Final selection doesn't match pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make "Spinning Wheel" type of game, in that the user can choose three possible outcomes, and then, after they can spin the wheel, if any of the chosen three come up then he/she is a winner.

In the demo below you can see that, after spinner stops, the result is not the right value. After spinner itself stops it continues and changes the value -- and in before the last it's always the lightbulb. (Please view this FULLSCREEN to see what I'm referring to.)

How can I fix this?

```js
//set default degree (360*5)
var degree = 1800;
//number of clicks = 0
var clicks = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 /*WHEEL SPIN FUNCTION*/
 $('#spin').click(function(){
  
  //add 1 every click
  clicks ++;
  
  /*multiply the degree by number of clicks
   generate random number between 1 - 360, 
    then add to the new degree*/
  var newDegree = degree*clicks;
  var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  totalDegree = newDegree+extraDegree;
  
  /*let's make the spin btn to tilt every
  time the edge of the section hits 
  the indicator*/
  $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
   var t = $(this);
   var noY = 0;
   
   var c = 0;
   var n = 700; 
   var interval = setInterval(function () {
    c++;    
    if (c === n) { 
     clearInterval(interval);    
    } 
     
    var aoY = t.offset().top;
    $("#txt").html(t.html());
    console.log(aoY);
    
    /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
    each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
    So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
    that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
    exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
    if(aoY < 23.89){
     console.log('<<<<<<<<');
     $('#spin').addClass('spin');
     setTimeout(function () { 
      $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
     }, 100); 
    }
   }, 10);
   
   $('#inner-wheel').css({
    'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'   
   });
   
   noY = t.offset().top;
   
  });
 });
 
 
 
});//DOCUMENT READY
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

body{
 background:#eaeaea;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

a{
 color:#34495e; 
}




/*WRAPPER*/
#wrapper{ 
 margin: 40px auto 0; 
 width:266px; 
 position:relative;
}

#txt{
 color:#000; 
}


/*WHEEL*/
#wheel{
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 border-radius:50%; 
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:8px solid #fff;
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0px 3px 0px;
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#wheel:before{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 width:242px;
 height:242px;
 border-radius:50%;
 z-index:1000; 
}

#inner-wheel{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 -moz-transition:    all 6 cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 -o-transition:      all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 -ms-transition:     all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 transition:         all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99); 
}

#wheel div.sec{
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 130px 75px 0;
 border-color: #19c transparent;
 transform-origin: 75px 129px;
 left:50px;
 top:-4px; 
 opacity:1;
}

#wheel div.sec:nth-child(1){
 transform: rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
 border-color: #16a085 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(2){
 transform: rotate(120deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
 border-color: #2980b9 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(3){
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
 border-color: #34495e transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(4){
 transform: rotate(240deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(240deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
 border-color: #f39c12 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(5){
 transform: rotate(300deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
 border-color: #d35400 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(6){
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 border-color: #c0392b transparent; 
}


#wheel div.sec .fa{
 margin-top: -100px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10000000;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:36px;
 margin-left:-15px;
 
 text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px;
}




#spin{
 width:68px;
 height:68px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:-34px 0 0 -34px;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 3px 0px;
 z-index:1000;
 background:#fff;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;   
}


#spin:after{
 content:"SPIN"; 
 text-align:center;
 line-height:68px;
 color:#CCC;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 100000;
 width:68px;
 height:68px;
 display:block;
}

#spin:before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 20px 28px 20px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
 top:-12px;
 left:14px;
}

#inner-spin{
 width:54px;
 height:54px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:-27px 0 0 -27px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:red;
 z-index:999;
 box-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px -2px 0px inset, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 2px 0px inset,  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px ;
 
 background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(234,234,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */ 
}

#spin:active #inner-spin{
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px inset;
}

#spin:active:after{
 font-size:15px; 
}



#shine{
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99)), color-stop(9%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */


opacity:0.1;
 
}



/*ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes hh {
  0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hh {
   0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

.spin {
  -webkit-animation: hh 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: hh 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
            
        <div id="wheel">
            <div id="inner-wheel">
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-bell-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-smile-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></span></div>
            </div>       
           
            <div id="spin">
                <div id="inner-spin"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="shine"></div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="txt"></div>
  </div>
```

If there is any other demo similar like my functionality. then Help may be appropriated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: what you don't understand?

Comment: What you're asking. For example, "However after spinner Stop its continues Changes the value. and in last it come bulb always" makes no sense.

Comment: can you please run the snippet code on fullpage?  when spin stop. arrow dosent shows right selected panel.

Comment: [Fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/nmtc6PAXrjgBGyzdBLXe) interval cleaning and added calculation of winning sec.

Comment: @Artem ohh yes my friend its working.. thanks a lot dear

Comment: @IshanShah On "continues Changes the value": setInterval runs updates for each .sec in infinite loop. It should be cleared at the end of transformation. Another issue is #txt is updated with each .sec, no matter if it is selected or not.

Comment: @Artem Please put your findings in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason I have the strange urge to play Trivia Crack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The [setInterval() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) will continue calling the function until
>   [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) is called, or the window is closed.

setInterval returns ID required for clearInterval.

Clear interval timers and show result after transition (6100ms).

```js
var degree = 1800;
var clicks = 0;

//Clear interval timer if id saved in attributes:
function clear_interval(t) {
  var interval = parseInt(t.data('interval'));
  if(interval > 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    t.data('interval', '');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#spin').click(function(){
    clicks ++;
    var newDegree = degree*clicks;
    var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    totalDegree = newDegree+extraDegree;

    //Calculate result index:
    var win_num = 6 - Math.floor((totalDegree % 360 + 30) / 60);
  
    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
      var t = $(this);
      
      clear_interval(t);
      
      //Save timer ID in data-interval attribute:
      t.data('interval', setInterval(function () {
        var aoY = t.offset().top;
        $("#txt").html(t.html());

        if(aoY < 23.89){
          $('#spin').addClass('spin');
          setTimeout(function () { 
            $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
          }, 100); 
        }
      }, 10));
   
      $('#inner-wheel').css({
        'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'   
      });
    });

    //Stop updates and show result when transition already ended:
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
        clear_interval($(this));
      });
      $("#txt").html($('#wheel div.sec:nth-child('+win_num+')').html());
    }, 6100);
  });
});
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

body{
 background:#eaeaea;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

a{
 color:#34495e; 
}




/*WRAPPER*/
#wrapper{ 
 margin: 40px auto 0; 
 width:266px; 
 position:relative;
}

#txt{
 color:#000; 
}


/*WHEEL*/
#wheel{
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 border-radius:50%; 
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:8px solid #fff;
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0px 3px 0px;
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#wheel:before{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 width:242px;
 height:242px;
 border-radius:50%;
 z-index:1000; 
}

#inner-wheel{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 -moz-transition:    all 6 cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 -o-transition:      all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 -ms-transition:     all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
 transition:         all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99); 
}

#wheel div.sec{
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 130px 75px 0;
 border-color: #19c transparent;
 transform-origin: 75px 129px;
 left:50px;
 top:-4px; 
 opacity:1;
}

#wheel div.sec:nth-child(1){
 transform: rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
 border-color: #16a085 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(2){
 transform: rotate(120deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
 border-color: #2980b9 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(3){
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
 border-color: #34495e transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(4){
 transform: rotate(240deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(240deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
 border-color: #f39c12 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(5){
 transform: rotate(300deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
 border-color: #d35400 transparent; 
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(6){
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 border-color: #c0392b transparent; 
}


#wheel div.sec .fa{
 margin-top: -100px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10000000;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:36px;
 margin-left:-15px;
 
 text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px;
}




#spin{
 width:68px;
 height:68px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:-34px 0 0 -34px;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 3px 0px;
 z-index:1000;
 background:#fff;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;   
}


#spin:after{
 content:"SPIN"; 
 text-align:center;
 line-height:68px;
 color:#CCC;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 100000;
 width:68px;
 height:68px;
 display:block;
}

#spin:before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 20px 28px 20px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
 top:-12px;
 left:14px;
}

#inner-spin{
 width:54px;
 height:54px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:-27px 0 0 -27px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:red;
 z-index:999;
 box-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px -2px 0px inset, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 2px 0px inset,  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px ;
 
 background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(234,234,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */ 
}

#spin:active #inner-spin{
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px inset;
}

#spin:active:after{
 font-size:15px; 
}



#shine{
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99)), color-stop(9%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */


opacity:0.1;
 
}



/*ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes hh {
  0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hh {
   0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

.spin {
  -webkit-animation: hh 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: hh 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
            
        <div id="wheel">
            <div id="inner-wheel">
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-bell-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-smile-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></div>
                <div class="sec"><span class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></span></div>
            </div>       
           
            <div id="spin">
                <div id="inner-spin"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="shine"></div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="txt"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How should i increse the wheel size? Have you idea or aware of it?